# Unicode list to integer ; R

Tags: r, unicode, integer, dataframe

One of my variables in a data frame is unicode (all cases are numbers).

```
head(total$Page)
[u'0'] [u'0'] [u'6'] [u'1'] [u'2']
```

How do I convert it into integers, so that:

```
head(total$Page)
0, 0, 6, 1, 2
```

Thanks.

EDIT. dput:

```
dput(head(total$Page))
structure(c(1L, 1L, 36L, 2L, 13L, 4L), .Label = c("[u'0']", "[u'1']", 
"[u'10']", "[u'11']", "[u'12']", "[u'13']", "[u'14']", "[u'15']", 
"[u'16']", "[u'17']", "[u'18']", "[u'19']", "[u'2']", "[u'20']", 
"[u'21']", "[u'22']", "[u'23']", "[u'24']", "[u'25']", "[u'26']", 
"[u'27']", "[u'28']", "[u'29']", "[u'3']", "[u'30']", "[u'31']", 
"[u'32']", "[u'33']", "[u'34']", "[u'35']", "[u'37']", "[u'38']", 
"[u'39']", "[u'4']", "[u'5']", "[u'6']", "[u'67']", "[u'7']", 
"[u'8']", "[u'9']", "[]", "[u'36']", "[u'40']", "[u'41']", "[u'42']", 
"[u'43']", "[u'44']"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `dput(head(total$Page))` to it.

Comment: @Roland I've edited it.

Comment: Maybe `as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", x))` if only have integers there

Comment: or `as.integer(gsub("[^[:digit:]]*", "", x))`

Comment: Thanks guys! it worked.

Comment: @Zlo what happens when you read in that CSV file (assuming it's a CSV file) with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and set an encoding for the file?

Comment: What do you mean by “Unicode” here? It doesn’t seem to match the usual, standard definition of Unicode. Am I correct in thinking that you simply have a character string where each value has the format `"[u'x']"`?